# Date format and getting results form last 24 hours

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting, to-date, ora-01843

I am new to SQL and I am having an issue with the query below. I need to return the order sessions that were entered in the last 24 hours, the query returns all order sessions if I don't have the last statement in there, but I only need the ones from the last 24 hours. CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT is not an Oracle Date a number that needs to be converted to a readable date using ddt.tochar.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         CCDBA.O_PAT.SESSION_ID, 
         CCDBA.PATIENT.MEDREC_ID "MRN",
         CCDBA.PATIENT.VISIT_NUMBER "Account Number",
         CCDBA.PATIENT.LAST_NAME || ', ' || CCDBA.PATIENT.FIRST_NAME "Patient",
         CCDBA.PATIENT.DEPT_ID "Floor",
         CCDBA.PATIENT.ROOM_ID "Room",
         ddt.tochar(CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT) "Order Date"
  FROM CCDBA.PATIENT
 INNER JOIN CCDBA.O_PAT ON CCDBA.O_PAT.PAT_SEQ = CCDBA.PATIENT.PAT_SEQ
 WHERE CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_ID = '681278'
  AND TO_DATE(ddt.tochar(CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT), 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
        >= SYSDATE -1;
```

I get the folloing error:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

The raw data from `CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT` looks like this: `7686745377`
The data from looks `CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT` like this after converting using ddt.tochar: `02/20/14 09:58`

Comment: What is the data type of CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT column and what does ddt.tochar return?

Comment: it is an oracle date column, data type = NUMBER(10,0). ddt.tochar returns the converted oracle date in a format we can read.

Comment: NUMBER is NOT a date column.  Not a good ideas to store dates as numbers.  Problem is that your tochar function returns a format that probably does not match your format mask.

Comment: McKesson my friend made that database, I am just working with what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert a date to a string and back again to compare dates.  Simplify the condition:

```
WHERE CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_ID = '681278' AND
      CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT >= SYSDATE - 1;
```

Also, if you are learning SQL, learn to use table aliases.  The resulting queries are easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.SESSION_ID, 
       p.MEDREC_ID  as "MRN",
       p.VISIT_NUMBER as "Account Number",
       p.LAST_NAME || ', ' || p.FIRST_NAME as "Patient",
       p.DEPT_ID as "Floor",
       p.ROOM_ID as "Room",
       ddt.tochar(o.ORDER_DDT) as "Order Date"
FROM CCDBA.PATIENT p INNER JOIN
     CCDBA.O_PAT o
     ON o.PAT_SEQ = p.PAT_SEQ
WHERE o.ORDER_ID = '681278' AND c.ORDER_DDT >= SYSDATE - 1;
```

And, if you don't need `DISTINCT`, don't use it.  It just wastes processing time when not needed.

EDIT:

For the revised date format:

```
WHERE CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_ID = '681278' AND
      TO_DATE(ddt.tochar(CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT),
              'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') >= sysdate - 1;
```

Comment: I get this error:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 12 Column: 28

Comment: Is your database storing dates as anything other than a date?  You should clarify the question.

Comment: I edited the question, the CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT is an oracle date, it is a number that has to be converted to a date using the ddt.tochar.

Comment: In that case, the format string is wrong.  Please edit your question and include some sample values of what `o.ORDER_DDT` looks like and what `ddt.tochar(o.ORDER_DDT)` looks like.

Comment: The raw data from CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT looks like this: 7686745377 The data from looks CCDBA.O_PAT.ORDER_DDT like this after converting using ddt.tochar: 02/20/14 09:58

Comment: This runs without difficulty (THANK YOU!) but returns no rows and the ORDER_ID had orders placed on it today. Hmm...

Comment: Sysdate only returns a date, no time. DD-MON-YY I wounder if that can be the issue.

Comment: `sysdate` returns a date *with* a time.  Perhaps the time doesn't get printed, but it is there.

Comment: Even with doing SYSDATE, DD-MON-YY 24HH:MM:SS the column only returns the date. McKesson may have altered the return.